# "Barbed" fastener, ideally with a release

Tags: fasteners

I'm trying to identify a fastener or type of fastener.  I have a stud/post that comes up through a board and the fastener is something that would push on and hold in place.  Ideally it would be removable.

[image: Fastener to stud]

Comment: I assume the board is a circuit board? rough dimensions? What do you want to fasten to the board?

Comment: There are many types of these fasteners used in auto trim,etc. Some have releases.

Comment: https://www.ebay.co.uk/p/9021792497?iid=183565857632